# English terminology MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, terminology

I need help with some "terminology" about query parts. But not only query PARTS, any "query-related figures of speech" also will be very helpful, I'm strongly interested in them. And not only about `SELECT`s (as in example below), `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s and other queries.

For example:

```
SELECT t1.f1, t1.f2, t2.f1 AS f1a, (t2.f2 * 10) AS f2a
FROM talbe1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t1.f4 <> t2.f4)
WHERE t1.f3 > t2.f3
LIMIT 100, 9999
```

I know that:

1) `t1, t2` - "table aliases", no mistake here?

2) `f1a` - "field alias", `f2a` - idk... "expression alias" maybe? Is there a difference between them? Any collective naming?

3) `100` - "offset"

I'm not sure how to call:

1) all between `SELECT` and `FROM`: `t1.f1, t1.f2, t2.f1 AS f1a, (t2.f2 * 10) AS f2a`

2) `t1.f3 > t2.f3` "where clause"? "condition"? which is better? other variants?

3) `(t1.f4 <> t2.f4)` "join condition"?

Also interested if there is more than 1 join, can I call them somehow by "order" or "depth"? And if I can do it by "depth" then how it will be with the `RIGHT JOIN`?

Any other interesting "naming of things" with your examples will be very helpful. Like SELF-JOIN, may be some other of joins which have special call, anything interesting you can remember.

Comment: As @francis-usher advises in [their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31700484/4265352), reading the official documentation (find it at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) is the best way to get the terminology. And stop worrying about your English.

Comment: @axiac thats almost not MY English. question have alot of editions :)

Comment: indeed, it took this shape after some community effort. Didn't notice this before ;-)

Comment: @M0rtiis I for one try to only flag questions as for their language when the OP doesn't put the effort in.  If OP puts in the effort (like you), I might suggest an edit but would never flag, vote down etc.  I hope other denizens of the web act accordingly :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQL is very formal and it is really well structured.
Any **query** (regardless `SELECT` or `INSERT` etc.) consists of **сlauses**. For `SELECT`-queries I suggest to start reading it from the `FROM`-clause. In others start from `DELETE`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE`clauses (first line). These clauses show ***which datasets are being manipulated***. In these clauses you can see a table or a list or tables or `JOIN`-expressions (in `FROM`) or *subqueries* in parenthesis. List of tables also means join but will be explained later. E.g.

```
... FROM tab1 t1  
... FROM tab1 t1, tab2 t2
... FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 ON ( ... )
... FROM (select * from tab3 ...) t
DELETE tab4 ...  /* doesn't delete the table, but its records*/
INSERT INTO tab5 ...
UPDATE tab6 t6 ...
UPDATE (select * from tab3 ... ) ...
```

These are central clauses which shows what tables are to be processed.

Within the clause each table or subquery could be referenced using an **alias**. Aliases will replace the table name in all other parts of the query. In above examples *t1*, *t2*, *t6* and *t* are aliases. Most DBMSs doesn't require the word `AS` before alias, and many doesn't allow it. If an alias is present you have to use this alias only.

All queries (except `INSERT`) could contain `WHERE`-clauses. This clause limits the number of affected rows. It contains a **condition**. It is possible to give a single simple condition of one comparison (e.g. `last_name="Ellison"`) or complex conditions which additionally uses *logical operators*: `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`. Different parts of the condition could be grouped by parenthesises.

```
WHERE t1.last_name="Ellison" AND t1.first_name="Clark"
WHERE usr.id=profile.usr_id AND
     (usr.state="active" OR usr.role="contributor")
```

Other clauses are specific to queries. `SELECT`-clauses contains a list of expressions and gives the **projection** — produces new set of columns for processed recordset. Any expression could contain **column aliases** added using the optional word `AS`.

`ORDER BY`-clauses controls the order of result records (or result set). It is applicable to `SELECT`-query only. `ORDER BY` must be the last clause.

`GROUP BY`-clauses and `HAVING`-clauses are used for grouping certain records into one and filtering the result after grouping. Grouping replaces multiple records (which has same value in one or several fields) into one record. These clauses are applicable to `SELECT`-query.

A `SELECT` query could be (where square brackets indicate optional parts):

```
SELECT expressions
FROM tables or join expressions
[WHERE simple or complex condition]
[GROUP BY expressions
 [HAVING simple or complex condition]]
[ORDER BY expressions]
```

Others are simpler:

```
DELETE table
[WHERE simple or complex condition]

UPDATE table
SET field=expression, field=expression, ...
[WHERE simple or complex condition]

INSERT INTO table[(fields...)]
VALUES (expressions...)
```

or another form

```
INSERT INTO table[(fields...)]
SELECT...   /* normal select-query */
```

---

### Regarding `JOIN`

`JOIN` is an implementation of a relational algebra operation. When joining some record of one table it concatenates this with a record of another table and makes a wider record. `INNER JOIN` (exact join) applies this action to only pairs of records which matches the joining condition.

```
... users INNER JOIN roles ON (roles.id=user.role_id) ...
```

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` additionally adds unmatched records from the first table into the result set. `RIGHT JOIN` vice-versa.

```
-- two identical joins using different join operators
... users LEFT OUTER JOIN roles ON (roles.id=user.role_id)...
... roles RIGHT OUTER JOIN users ON (roles.id=user.role_id)...
```

`FULL OUTER JOIN` does both, it gives the result of an `INNER JOIN` plus unmatched records from left table plus unmatched records from right table.

Words `INNER` and `OUTER` are optional. You can omit them and nothing changes.

Comment: it adds more "formality". u helped alot

Answer (score 15):

You may be interested in what [the official MySQL syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) has to say about the matter. In my opinion you can never be overly formal when trying to describe something as mathematical as programming language terminology.

### 1.

`t1.f1` is called a **select_expr**, fudge-pronounced in English as "select expression". Note that:

> Each `select_expr` indicates a column that you want to retrieve.

So another less formal way of calling it in English would probably be "column."

### 2.

The syntax seems to distinguish between the *clause* and the *condition*, where the clause includes the keyword `WHERE` itself, but the condition is just the plain-old SQL expression inside.

> The `WHERE` clause, if given, indicates the condition or conditions that rows must satisfy to be selected. `where_condition` is an expression that evaluates to true for each row to be selected.

and also

> In the `WHERE` expression, you can use any of the functions and operators that MySQL supports, except for aggregate (summary) functions. See Section 9.5, “Expression Syntax”

### 3.

From a different [syntax documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

> MySQL supports the following `JOIN` syntaxes for the `table_references` part of `SELECT` statements

So the whole part about which tables to `SELECT` from is called the "table references". From here we can dig into the syntax a bit for the production which matches your above example:

```
join_table: table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]
```

This means the part you're referring to is contained within the "join condition." However as with the `WHERE` clause above, the join condition also contains the `ON` keyword. The actual expression `(t1.f4 <> t2.f4)` is, again, a plain-old `conditional_expr` or "conditional expression", just like the one from the `WHERE` clause above.

Some more details from this doc page yield a valuable insight:

> The `conditional_expr` used with ON is any conditional expression of the form that can be used in a WHERE clause. Generally, you should use the ON clause for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the WHERE clause to restrict which rows you want in the result set.

So you could informally distinguish between them in a useful, meaningful way by calling your `WHERE` condition a "row-restriction expression" and the `JOIN` condition a "join condition expression."

Comment: I learned a lot too! I didn't know any of this stuff before I looked it up today. Thanks for asking a good question.

Comment: sorry.. but wtf. the owner of this answer was another man. "Francais Uther" somth near that. And im talking not only about nickname, that was tatally another account, according to reputation, count of answers, badges, etc. What happend?

Comment: ILLUMINATI!!! INCEPTION!!! Nah JK, since I couldn't access my personal gmail at work I had created that account. Now I merged my 2 accounts so I can access them with either email, at work or at home. Thanks for the bounty btw!

Comment: ok then) i didnt know about account-merge possibility) sorry & thx

Answer (score 10):

Q: **1) all between `SELECT` and `FROM`:** t1.f1, t1.f2, t2.f1 AS f1a, (t2.f2 * 10) AS f2a

A: I refer to that as the "**select list**". That's the list of **expressions** that are being returned. Each expression in the list is a column in the resultset. (An expression can be as simple as a column name, or can be more involved, the return from a function or comparison operation.

Q: **2) t1.f3 > t2.f3 "where clause"? "condition"? which is better? other variants?**

A: The general term for these conditions that have to be satisfied in order for a row to be returned is a "**predicate**". The predicates are the conditions in the `WHERE` clause or `ON` clauses that have to be satisfied in order for a row to be returned.

Q: **3) (t1.f4 <> t2.f4) "join condition"?**

A: Again, this is a **predicate**. This just happens to appear in the ON clause rather than the `WHERE` clause. The term "join condition" is also appropriate. But in terms of how that database parses and executes the statement, it's just another predicate.

Normative practice is for a "join condition" to be included in the `ON` clause, and other conditions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 6):

1) 2) I would use aliases that show what they refer to. For example, `select ... from my_first_table mft inner join user_rights ur where ...` .
But if you don't have better options, "t1, t2, ..." are OK.

3) yes

---

1) select clause, or fields

2) where clause

3) "join condition" is right

Comment: thx for your response. i think in example `t1` shows that it refers to `table1`, 2 too :)

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have understood most of the terms quite good, I would say, and I do believe you would be understood with most of your wording. Looking towards the formal documentation also seems like a good idea.

Here are my take on your questions, first lets respond to those you seem to know:

1. "Table aliases" is good
2. "field alias" or "expression alias" are good. A common answer could be "column alias", as these statements defines the columns of your result
3. "offset" (or possibly "row offset") is good

The ones you are not so sure about:

1. Between the `SELECT` and `FROM` I would either use "select expression" or "column expression" or "column definitions"
2. I tend to use "where expressions"
3. "join condition" or "join expression" are equally clear to me

When referring to the different joins, I would either differentiate them by the only "inner join" or "left join", or if you have multiple joins then use something like the "join on table1". "Self join" would of course refer to a join referring back to itself using a different alias, but could become confusing if you have lots of other joins as well.

In general most people would be understanding, and disregard minor errors in wording, as long as your intentions and the solution is understood.